# ¿Como pasar a un constructor de la clase principal una referencia de la misma?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, constructor, ventana

El caso es que estoy haciendo una calculadora para mis clases de programación, nada complicado pero esto atascado en el final. Tengo una clase VentanaPrincipal que es la interfaz gráfica creada con swing. Y tengo una clase PanelOperaciones, donde estoy haciendo las operaciones con los botones "Sumar" y "Restar". En el libro que utilizamos leí que para poder utilizar métodos de la clase "mundo" del problema (Calculadora con métodos sumar y restar) tenía que crear una relación de la clase PanelOperaciones a la VentanaPrincipal, y como esta tenía ya una relación con la clase mundo, podría utilizar sus métodos sin problema. Esto me funciona pero dice que modifique el constructor de la clase PanelOperaciones de modo que queda así:

```
private VentanaPrincipal principal; //Esto está antes del constructor, solo lo pongo aquí para ahorrar espacio.

public PanelOperaciones( VentanaPrincipal v ) {
    principal = v;

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JButton btSumar = new JButton("Sumar");
    JButton btRestar = new JButton("Restar");

    btRestar.setActionCommand(RESTAR);
    btRestar.addActionListener(this);
    btSumar.setActionCommand(SUMAR);
    btSumar.addActionListener(this);

    add(btSumar);
    add(btRestar);
}
```

En el libro que utilizo me sale que debo dejar la instancia de la relación así: principal = v;
El problema viene en que la clase Ventana Principal también tengo una relación con la clase panelOperaciones. Así que, cuando la instancio me pide el valor "v" que es una referencia a su misma clase, como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Probablemente con `this` desde `VentanaPrincipal`, pero porque ambas clases deben tener una referencia una a la otra?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!